# Why some python statements in Sconstruct are not executed？

Tags: python, scons

There are multiple c language files in a folder. I don't want to compile all c files every time. I wrote a Sconstruct. I want to use some options to control which file is compiled.

```
import os
import sys
input = sys.argv
env = Environment(CC = 'gcc')
env.Program('testC','cExample.c')
```

The above code can be executed normally. But the following code shows scons: Nothing to be done for `cExample.c` when I use `scons cExample.c`. The testC file is not generated. I tested and found that it did enter the if statement

```
import os
import sys
env = Environment(CC = 'gcc')
# env.Program('testC','cExample.c')
if 'cExample.c' in sys.argv:    
    print('here')
    env.Program('testC','cExample.c')
```

It still shows

```
scons: Nothing to be done for `cExample.c'.
scons: done building targets.
```

I'm sorry for not explaining clearly. This code is written in a Sconstruct file. Its function is similar to MakeFile file. The sentence env.Program('testC','cExample.c') is to compile cExample.c into a testC executable file. If I put env.Program('testC','cExample.c') outside the if (like the commented fourth line), cExample.c can be compiled normally, if it is inside the if (like now As shown), cExample.c was not successfully compiled.

Comment: Not related to the problem: Don't use `input` as a variable, it's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: Then how should I get the options set by scons. For example, scons cExample.c. How do I get cExamplec.c in Sconstruct. All I know is sys.argv[1].

Comment: Just give the variable a different name. Or don't use the variable at all: `if 'cExample.c' in sys.argv:`

Comment: Like I said, this has nothing to do with the problem you're having, it's just a general point about writing Python scripts: don't use the names of built-in functions as variable names.

Comment: The problem still exists after the modification.As written in the question

Comment: Adding the `[1]` just made things worse.  That isn't going to work with `in`. - the way you had it before, if you passed in `cExample.c` as a command line argument, you should have gone into your `if` statement.

Comment: So now the code here is working, right?  It must recognize `cExample.c` and go into your `if` because it's obviously calling `env.Program`, or you'd get no output at all.  So from what I see, the problem isn't here, or if it is, all that can be wrong is that you're passing the wrong thing to `env.Program()`.

Comment: The problem remains unresolved. I can see it enters the if statement. But it still shows scons: Nothing to be done for `cExample.c'.. And no testC file is generated

Comment: If I comment out the if statement, and uncomment the fourth line. It will run normally. But that’s not what I want, I want to be able to choose which file to compile

Comment: But that has nothing to do with this code.  How do you expect us to know what's going on past this point?  We have no idea what the Environment object or the Program method are, or how your environment is set up.  The code you're showing us seems to be working.  What more can. we do?

Comment: Huh?  That's not possible.  Well, if you're doing it, it obviously IS possible.  But it makes no sense.  Be really sure it's that simple.  (and sorry I didn't recognize earlier that that was your problem )

Comment: Try changing it back right now.  Could it be that it was different just because you ran it for the first time, and now it will act differently either way? - It's telling you that everything is fine and it has already built `cExample.c`. So maybe that's the right behavior.

Comment: I added some description to the question. I don’t quite understand the meaning of your previous comment? I did not find the testC file generated in the folder. If the testC file already exists before running, it will show that the testC file is the latest, but this is obviously not the case.

Comment: You don't need to code special logic to get SCons to only build requested targets, you just need to specify them correctly. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you type:

```
scons cExample.c
```

Assuming that file is not generated, and just sitting on the disk, of course SCons will say

```
scons: Nothing to be done for `cExample.c'.
```

The file built from cExample.c would be cExample.o (or .obj or other suffix set for objects).

So:

```
scons cExample.o
```

Will instruct SCons to only build that file.

With a SConstruct as

```
env = Environment(CC = 'gcc')
my_obj = env.Object('cExample.c')
env.Alias('myobject',my_obj)
env.Program('testC',my_obj)
```

You could then run

```
scons myobject
```

And that would only compile your .c -> .o

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this does not seem to work. It still shows scons: Nothing to be done for `cExample.c'. I want to directly compile and link into an executable file

Comment: @cyj - I guess you missed my whole explanation above. No build system will ever have any actions due for a file which already exists and is not dynamically built.  You either want to build the object file, or the executable, in which case you should specify THAT target on the command line.

Comment: Let's add a bit of explain: a bare `scons` tells it to build the default targets. The target you've defined is in your one builder call - `Program`, so `testC`. When you give scons a non-option argument, that's the target to build. So in the second invocation you're asking it to build `cExample.c`, which already exists. To pass that to be used for other purposes you need to wrap it so it doesn't look like a target. See for example https://scons.org/doc/4.0.1/HTML/scons-man.html#sconscript_variables.